# Twitter4j redirect to previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity, twitter4j

I am new to working with the Twitter4J library and am running into a bit of a problem in Android. So I currently have an activity stack like A,B,C,D. From activity D I login to twitter using twitter4J. When the twitter login redirects back to my activity, it creates a new instance of the activity on the stack. The stack becomes A,B,C,D,TwitterLogin,D. I need my application to return to the state A,B,C,D so selecting the back button will pop activity D and bring activity C to the front.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I would achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) to the intent that you launch in order to start Activity D should do the trick. Something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Big help, thank you! I should read through android's navigation more thoroughly.

Comment: Just  wondering, in what intent did you put the flag @PPierson ? in Activity C ?? or you put the flag in the twitterlogin intent ? i am having the same issue here, my back stack gets cleared totally after i return from twitter intent.